# Load Spring profile specific yml file programattically and bind it to @ConfigurationProperties class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

`I have three profiles yml file:- application-dev.yml application-uat.yaml application-qa.yml`

Task:- I want to read properties of application-dev.yaml if I am passing gitlabBranch=develop from rest controller and application-uat if branch=master.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sdlc")
public class ApplicationConfig{
private String tenantId;
}

In controller-
```

```
Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource("classpath:application-dev.yml")
PropertySource test = loader.load("config",resource).get(0);
```

I want to map test.getSources() which are in map key and value pairs like 'sdlc.tenantId' to map to Custom Object ApplicationConfig class so I can use getters directly to retrieve values.

Comment: In Controller :-

```
Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource("classpath:application-dev.yml")
PropertySource test = loader.load("config",resource).get(0);

```

Comment: Task:- I want to read properties of application-dev.yaml if I am passing gitlabBranch=develop from rest controller and application-uat if branch=master.